# python return dictionary in separate lines in __repr__ method

Tags: python, dictionary, repr

I'm need to return my dictionary generated in the class using **repr** method, and i want it to return in separate lines.

Is there any way i can do it?

```
def __repr__:
    return str(self.maze)
```

expected:

```
{
(0, 0):[(0, 1), (1, 0)]
(0, 1):[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
(1, 0):[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
(1, 1):[(0, 1), (1, 0)]
}
```

what i got:

```
{(0, 1): [(0, 0), (1, 1)], (1, 0): [(0, 0), (1, 1)], (0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)], (1, 1): [(0, 1), (1, 0)]}
```

since i can't use "pprint"  I don't know if there's any other way i can do it.

Comment: Why can't you use `pprint` exactly?

Comment: it gives me a syntax error when i use pprint in repr, and also print won't let me change line after curly braces

Comment: I'm willing to bet you're getting a syntax error because you wrong `def __repr__:` with no arguments, instead of `def __repr__(self):`.

Comment: @abarent actually i do have arguments which is `def __repr__(self)`

Comment: multiline reprs are kind of rude, and don't work well when they're embedded in bigger structures.  perhaps use a different name for this method?

Comment: @Eevee: NumPy uses a multiline `repr`, and people don't usually complain about that. If you've got something that's inherently going to wrap around to multiple lines, why not format it a bit?

Comment: @Eevee: But that brings up another point: a `repr` that can be evaluated as Python code really should evaluate to the original object; this obvious won't, it'll evaluate to the dict member of the object. So maybe this should be a `__str__`, or normal named method, as you say…

Comment: @Blaaaakuu: Well, using `pprint` in a `repr` doesn't cause a SyntaxError. You may have written syntactically erroneous code that happened to use `pprint`, but the problem is your syntax, not the existence of that module.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a good reason for not being able to use `pprint` ... But this shouldn't be that hard:

```
def __repr__(self):
    inner_lines = '\n'.join('%s:%s' % (k, v) for k, v in self.maze.items())
    return """\
{
%s
}""" % inner_lines
```

e.g.:

```
>>> def fmt_dct(d):
...   inner_lines = '\n'.join('%s:%s' % (k, v) for k, v in d.items())
...   return """\
... {
... %s
... }""" % inner_lines
... 
>>> print fmt_dct(d)
{
(0, 1):['abcdefg']
(0, 2):['foo', 'bar']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, if the only reason you think you can't use `pprint` is because you haven't looked at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) and assume `pprint.pprint` is the only thing in the module—well, it's not, and even if it were, you could always create a `StringIO` and pass it in as the `stream` argument.

But if you want to do it manually, of course you can. You just need to think through the rules, and translate them to Python.

Let's write it the long way:

```
def __repr__(self):
    lines = ['{']
    for key, value in self.maze.items():
        lines.append('{}:{}'.format(key, value))
    lines.append(['}'])
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

If you know how to write list comprehensions, you can probably turn that into a one-liner; if not, either go learn, or keep it as 5 lines.